# Selenium IDE 1.0.8 and RC 1.0.3 Won't Click in Firefox 3.6.12 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium

Isn't it always the way, I'm finally ready to start using Selenium to test my web changes, and now I can't get it to work.

Subject line may say it all: environment is Ubuntu 10.04, Selenium components are all the most recent ones available. I'm trying to reproduce the Google example used in RC, using both RC and IDE.  There are two failure modes:

1. By far the most common is that "click" doesn't ever seem to click. Selenium executes the clic, but the page never changes.
2. A couple of times (when messing around with little changes to see if it fixes anything), clicks do seem to go through; but then Selenium doesn't appear to detect the page change on WaitForPage (I'll try to isolate one of these).

I've tried RC with Ruby, Perl and Java, and I get variations on this behavior. Since FF is my primary platform, I haven't yet tried to see if any other browser works...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 1.0.9
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.0.9/